# substring conversion (in Haskell). Can you beat this?

Tags: code-golf

Ok, I found myself with a nice little problem:

you will get from `stdin` a string. In this string you will find some hex colors (like `#ff00dd`). You must return the string with the colors inverted (`#ff00dd` inverted is `#00ff11`).

A sample input/output could be:

```
ascscasad #ff00ff csdcas dcs c#001122 #qq5500
ascscasad #00ff00 csdcas dcs c#ffeedd #qq5500
```

As I am proficient in Haskell, I tackled the problem with it. Came up with this code, and I think it's the best I can do. Do you see any way to improve it / a completely different way to make it shorter?

```
import Text.Regex.Posix ( (=~) )

main = getLine >>= putStrLn . f

f [] = []
f x = let (b, q, p) = x =~ "#[0-f]{6}"
          c = '#' : ['0'..'f'] ++ "#"
          a = zip c (reverse c)
          r = map ( (maybe '@' id) . (flip lookup $ a) ) q
      in b ++ r ++ f p
```

I am also interested to compare other languages to Haskell, so post in other languages are welcome, too!

Comment: Shouldn't the inverse of `#ff00dd` be `#00ff22`?

Comment: main = interact f

Comment: Can we assume `#ff00` is equivalent to `#00ff00` (since it is)?

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 44 chars

Two different tweaks can get it to this length, one suggested by Primo:

```
s/#\K[\da-f]{6}/sprintf"%06x",~hex ff.$&/eg
```

Another one by playing around with the `/ee` modifier:

```
s/#\K[\da-f]{6}/"sprintf'%06x',~0xff$&"/eeg
```

Requires -p command line switch (1 char included in count).

Works for lower-case hex numbers (as in example).  An `i` switch added to the regex would make it work for upper-case as well (though not preserving the case of the original number).

Comment: Very nice solution. I see only one minor improvement: `(~0>>8)-hex$&` can be replaced by `~hex ff.$&`.

Answer (score 2):

### APL 86

Index origin zero. Takes either a single colour hex string or multiple space separated colour strings as screen input via ←⍞

```
,' ',h[⊃16,¨,¨⍉¨(⊂16 16)⊤¨255-16⊥¨⍉¨(⊂3 2)⍴¨(⊂h←'0123456789abcdef#')⍳¨(c≠' ')⊂c←⍞~'#']


input: #ff00dd  output: #00ff22

input: #ff00dd #00ff22 output: #00ff22 #ff00dd
```

Comment: APL strikes again... :) Nice solution though!

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 46 bytes

```rb
gets.gsub(/#(\h+)/){"#%06x"%(0xffffff^$1.hex)}
```